# IndexedDB - cursor applying filter doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have a problem with filtering using indexedDB.

I have users with name aaa, bbb, ccc and index is on name.

Here's my code and no matter which IDBKeyRange filter I apply on cursor, I get empty list. I tried with bound and lowerBound.

```
     const usersData = [
        { id: '1', name: 'bbb', email: 'bbb@somewhere.com' },
        { id: '2', name: 'aaa', email: 'aaa@somewhere.com' },
        { id: '3', name: 'ccc', email: 'ccc@somewhere.com' },
     ];
     let db;
     let request = window.indexedDB.open('test1', 1);
     
     request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(e);
     };         
     request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        db = e.target.result;
        console.log('success, db: ', db);            
     };
     
     request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        db = e.target.result;
        let objectStore = db.createObjectStore('user', { keyPath: 'id' });            
        for (let user of usersData) {
           objectStore.add(user);
        }
        objectStore.createIndex('name', 'name');         
     }
             
     function readAll() {
        let objectStore = db.transaction(['user'])
        .objectStore('user');

        let range = null;
        //range = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound('aaa', true);  // ? doesn't working
        range = IDBKeyRange.bound(['aaa'], ['ccc'], true, true);

        objectStore.openCursor(range).onsuccess = function(e) {
           let cursor = e.target.result;               
           if (cursor) {
              console.log(cursor.key, cursor.value);
              cursor.continue();
           } 
           else {
              console.log('---------------------------------');
           }
        };
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code so that you open the cursor on the index, not the object store.

```js
// ...
let index = objectStore.index('name');
// ...
index.openCursor(range).onsuccess = // ...
// ...
```

Comment: nope, it didn't help: https://jsfiddle.net/cgtpbzyr/